# How to map ID to a different column In Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

When I have ID in the Domain class it worked fine

```
class Book {
    int id
    String bookAuthor

    static constraints = {
        bookAuthor blank: false, maxSize:30
    }

    static mapping = {    
        version false
        id generator: 'sequence',
        params: [sequence:'s_book_seq']
    }
}
```

But once I tried to map Id to BookId,

```
class Book {
    int bookId
    String bookAuthor

    static constraints = {
        bookAuthor blank: false, maxSize:30         
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        id generator: 'sequence',
        params: [sequence:'s_book_seq'], column :'bookId'
    }
}
```

Then Grails will fail to start my App. How to map ID to a different field?
The **`error`** i got is:

```
 Error|
 2014-12-27 00:16:01,293 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - ORA-00904: "THIS_"."B
    OOK_ID": invalid identifier
    Error |
    2014-12-27 00:16:01,412 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SQLSyntaxErro
    rException occurred when processing request: [GET] /gTunes/book/index
    ORA-00904: "THIS_"."BOOK_ID": invalid identifier
    . Stacktrace follows:
    Message: ORA-00904: "THIS_"."BOOK_ID": invalid identifier
        Line | Method
    ->>  445 | processError         in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    |    396 | processError         in     ''
    |    879 | processError . . . . in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall
    |    450 | receive              in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun
    |    192 | doRPC . . . . . . .  in     ''
    |    531 | doOALL               in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall
    |    207 | doOall8 . . . . . .  in oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement
    |    884 | executeForDescribe   in     ''
    |   1167 | executeMaybeDescribe in oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement
    |   1289 | doExecuteWithTimeout in     ''
    |   3584 | executeInternal . .  in oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement
    |   3628 | executeQuery         in     ''
    |   1493 | executeQuery . . . . in oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper
    |     43 | <init>               in grails.orm.PagedResultList
    |     15 | $tt__index . . . . . in test.myapp.BookController
    |    189 | doFilter             in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
    |     63 | doFilter . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
    |   1145 | runWorker            in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    |    615 | run . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
    ^    744 | run                  in java.lang.Thread
```

Update:

moise2022's solution worked. I can bring up the list page. However the generated ${bookInstance} in the show page is wrong.

```
<g:link class="edit" action="edit" resource="${bookInstance}"><g:message code="default.button.edit.label" default="Edit" /></g:link>
```

Instead of

```
<a href="/gTunes/book/edit/1" class="edit">Edit</a>
```

It generated

```
<a href="/gTunes/book/edit" class="edit">Edit</a>
```

So edit navigation broke

Update:

For Delete 
I tried to change

```
<g:form url="[resource:bookInstance, action:'delete' ]" method="DELETE">
```

to

```
<g:form url="[resource:bookInstance, action:'delete', id:'${bookInstance.bookId}' ]" method="DELETE">
```

That still didn't work.

```
URI:/gTunes/book/show/1Class:java.lang.IllegalArgumentExceptionMessage:named capturing group is missing trailing '}'
Around line 527 of grails-app\views\book\show.gsp


Around line 527 of AbstractFilter.java


Around line 50 of grails-app\views\book\show.gsp
47:                 <g:link class="edit" action="edit" id="${bookInstance.bookId}" ><g:message code="default.button.edit.label" default="Edit" /></g:link></td>48:                  <g:actionSubmit class="delete" action="delete" value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" />49:                </fieldset>50:          </g:form>51:        </div>52:   </body>53:</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the name arguments to change the name from the default id.

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'sequence',
    params: [sequence:'s_book_seq'], 
    name: 'bookId'
}
```

check the doc [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html) and read this [post](http://ilyasterin.com/blog/2009/09/gorm-custom-id-mapping.html)

Comment: @johnsam I guess since you are not using the default `id` name grails doesn't know what id to use. You will have to tell it what the id is. `<g:link class="edit" action="edit" id="${bookInstance.bookId}" resource="${bookInstance}"><g:message code="default.button.edit.label" default="Edit" /></g:link>`

Comment: Thanks I figured that out also. But still not able to make delete work. See my update.

Comment: I am guessing you have an action in your controller called delete. If so you can try using `<g:form name="myForm" action="delete" id:'${bookInstance.bookId}'>` You do not need to send back the entire object in order to delete a record.

Comment: also the [g:form][1] doc might help [1]http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/form.html

Comment: Yes. I got that. But I am not able to figure out the correct syntax to do that. The gsp code was generated by generate-forms command. I thought some tweak of g:form url attribute is necessary but not sure how.

Comment: The syntaxe you have is correct. Do you have the following tag in your html head section `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` if not add it and try again.